# Testing loading of a class in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, testing

I have some code in `+initialize` method of a class that I'd like to test (using simple OCUnit). Namely it's application delegate that sets some user defaults, so my testing would look like this:

1. Check for absence of values-to-be-set;
2. Load a class;
3. Check for presence and correctness of set values;

Do you have any hints on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup - You can move your defaults initialization implementation out to a separate function, which you call from `+[MONObject initialize]`.

Test the function in a lower level suite which does not load the objc class (`MONObject`) into the objc runtime.

Then you can test it and destroy it in a separate executable, and rely on that proof in your app level test suite.

Comment: It seems that I should get the separate target for lower level testing then (so that my AppDelegate class) would not be compiled/loaded). Do you think I'd get away with stubbing method calls on user defaults or with expectations of those methods calls with given values?

Comment: Exactly - the lower level suite would be a separate target which does not have all the app-land tests/types. The lower level target could create, validate, and destroy what it chose at each run (assuming serial testing). The app and the low level suite can share the initialization, behaviour, and error checking that the low level tests. If you want to *really* test it, you can also create dictionaries to test, and either save a dictionary to `standardUserDefaults` or use `dictionaryRepresentation`. If it's really complex, then you may just want to save one or more dictionaries as a key in SUD.

Answer (score 0):

When you set **"user defaults" defaults** it is only used when no other value has been stored in the "user defaults". So, if you call a value from "user defaults" you get the default value unless you have stored value in a previous run (note you have to delete the App on the device because "user defaults" are stored between runs).
You should set defaults for all "user defaults", because it only applies when used for the first time.

I may have misunderstood what you are asking but I think that you are mixing set values in the default and default values that are used when none have ever been set.

I am also confused why you are loading a class in +initialize class method, that gets called before any instance is created?

Comment: I usually put user defaults initialization into app delegate's `initialize` method because it's the first message that is being sent to the class that signifies if application has completed launching. This way I have all the needed user default values in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method.